# Where to find meteorological data from road stations?

Tags: meteorology, measurements, field-measurements

I am involved on a project that aims to analyze data from road weather stations, like the ones you can see from a German site here:

https://www.dwd.de/EN/ourservices/bufr_extensions_national/bufr_extensions_national.html
https://opendata.dwd.de/weather/weather_reports/road_weather_stations/

Does anyone know where I can find this kind of information from other countries? I am specially interested in analyzing Water Film Thickness.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you mean by water film thickness? I am in atmospheric sciences but never come across data that is being known as water film thickness! The closest thing I could think is precipitable water vapour, do you mean precipitable water vapour?